# iPhone - Switch Tab from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a webview and I want to manually switch to another tab during a specific event. The event is arbitray, but I can't figure out hwo to switch teh tab. On my other views, I have the following code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
```

However, this does not work in my custom UIWebView class. Is there a simple solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selectedIndex` property to change tab.

Which version the SDK are you using ?
Because prior to version 3.0, only the invisible tab could displayed by selectedViewController. (see the 3.0+ SDK doc for selectedViewController).